# Convert WiFi range extender to AP

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, openwrt, firmware

I have a Linksys RE1000 WiFi range extender that might become obsolete soon (being replaced with cables).

I was thinking, since it has an ethernet port and WiFi radio, could it be turned into an access point with a software hack?

Comment: Why slow it down?  If you pair this with an N router, you are going to have faster speeds than if you ran it off a cable (150-300 vs. 100).  It already is an "access point" of sorts... it just connects to a network via wireless as opposed to an ethernet cable, and you can't give it it's own SSID (it only rebroadcasts the signal it is set to pick up).

Comment: @Bon Gart The original access point (and cable modem) has bad wifi, or the reception is bad, therefore the cable.

Comment: Right... I wasn't addressing why you would need an AP... just why you would want to slow that particular device down.  There isn't a firmware replacement for it out on the web, and it is specifically designed to re-transmit the same connection information that is used to connect it to a wireless router... you enter in the information needed to connect it to a router, and it rebroadcasts that.  In fact, this is one of the faults... it uses the same channel, which can cause some overlap of signal.  You'd need to purchase an actual AP, since there are no software hacks for that specific product.

Comment: I think the reason are reliability and possibly speed. 100mbit wired is often a lot faster than 300mbit wireless. (Wired 100 Can do that speed. Even it you have dozens of PCs active at the same time. The wireless speed is under optimum conditions and the medium is shared)